# SQL to find max of delta values from same column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

Find:
max( abs( c(a=2) - c(a=1) ) )
order by b

Given Table T

```
a  b  c
-- -- --
1  1  2      
1  2  4
1  3  5
2  1  10
2  2  11
2  3  20
3  1  40
3  2  40
3  3  40
```

Example math:

```
c(@2) - c(@1) in order of b
10    - 2     = 8
11    - 4     = 7
20    - 5     = 15  <-- max found
```

I can get the answer for b=1 difference, but I want to simplify my query without cut and pasting additional where's b=1, b=2, b=3, etc.
Not sure if a cte applies here or a with recursive query that increments b?

Final working query:

```
SELECT
    coalesce(max(abs(rn.c - r0.c)), -999) AS rd --> RETURN nulls = -999.
FROM
    (SELECT b, c FROM t WHERE a = 1) AS r0
JOIN
    (SELECT b, c FROM t WHERE a = 2) AS rn
ON r0.b = rn.b;
```

Comment: Is your problem equivalent to `max of x where id = 2` - `min of x where id = 1`?

Comment: No, the query must compute delta's in lock step with f.

Comment: I can't see what is expected result and what query you tried.

Comment: I showed the desired result = 15?

Comment: Both answers below work. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table stk_test(a int ,b int, c int)

insert into stk_test
select 1,1,2
union
select 1,2,4
union
select 1,3,5
union
select 2,1,10
union
select 2,2,11
union
select 2,3,20
union
select 3,1,40
union
select 3,2,40
union
select 3,3,40

select max(abs(a.a_c-b.b_c)) as Max_Diff_C from
(
    select c as a_c,b from stk_test ss
    where a=1
) a  join  
(
    select c  as b_c,b from stk_test ssr
    where a=2
)b on a.b=b.b
```

Comment: I modified the table to match Mani Kandan's answer which seems to work! Let me double check...

Comment: Great work Mani! I owe you several beers!
    `SELECT
  max(abs(a.a_c - b.b_c)) AS cdiff
FROM
  (SELECT c AS a_c, b FROM t AS ss WHERE a = 1) AS a
  JOIN (SELECT c AS b_c, b FROM t AS ssr WHERE a = 3) AS b
  ON a.b = b.b;`

Comment: @skywalk the common way to say thank you on SO is to accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry, it was late. I will edit above to show minified working query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what you mean yet.
Possibly this may help.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
CREATE TABLE t( id integer,f integer, x integer);

INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,1,2), (1,2,4), (1,3,5);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2,1,10), (2,2,11), (2,3,20);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (3,1,40), (3,2,40), (3,3,40);

SELECT * from t;

SELECT MAX(ABS(sup.x - inf.x))
FROM  (SELECT f, MAX(x) x from t WHERE id = 2 GROUP BY f) sup
      INNER JOIN (select f, MIN(x) x FROM t WHERE id = 1 GROUP BY f) inf ON sup.f = inf.f
```

Tested with https://kripken.github.io/sql.js/GUI/

Comment: Thanks yskkin, your answer is also correct. I was confused by the extra stuff(MAX, MIN, GROUP BY) in your select's. Maybe those were while you were debugging the query? But, they are not necessary for the final result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one attempt using lead function which ranks data

```
create table t(a int, b int , c int)

insert into t values(1,1,2)      
insert into t values(1,2,4)
insert into t values(1,3,5)
insert into t values(2,1,10)
insert into t values(2,2,11)
insert into t values(2,3,20)
insert into t values(3,1,40)
insert into t values(3,2,40)
insert into t values(3,3,40)

with data
  as (select * /*First rank the results on the basis of columns a and b*/    
            ,row_number() over(order by a,b) as rnk
        from t
     )
,temp_data
  as (select a      
            ,b
            ,c
            ,rnk
            ,abs(c-lead(c,3) over(order by rnk)) as max_rnk
       from data
      )
select a,max(max_rnk) /*Gets the max value of rank grouped by each a*/      
  from temp_data
group by a
```

Demo using dbfiddle

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b7db648a2512b623a7df4351326fa25d